# Windows 7 Static IP Logs/History

Tags: windows-7, networking, logging, static-ip, event-log

Is there any way to pull up in the Event Log when a Static IP address was changed and if possible what changes were made?

I've run into a problem where someone keeps changing their static IP address and "losing the internet" and claiming they haven't modified a thing.

Any log anywhere in Windows 7 would be a great help!

Windows 7 Professional - SP1

Running in a Workgroup not on a domain